# ckeditor don't appear in django form

Tags: django, ckeditor, ckeditor5, django-ckeditor

I designed a web with Django . I use **CKEditor** for content of a model but after I connected my site to bucket storage, box CKA editor disappeared and won't upload so I can upload text, what's the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifn6p.jpg) what do I do?

Comment: You have to look in the browser console to see any errors. Please edit your question to include this info.